# Unable to log Flask exceptions with SMTP handler

Tags: python, logging, flask

I am attempting to get an email sent to me any time an error occurs in my Flask application.  The email is not being sent despite the handler being registered.  I used `smtplib` to verify that my SMTP login details are correct.  The error is displayed in Werkzeug's debugger, but no emails are sent.  How do I log exceptions that occur in my app?

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

if app.debug:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # all of the $ names have actual values
    handler = SMTPHandler(
        mailhost = 'smtp.mailgun.org',
        fromaddr = 'Application Bug Reporter <$mailgun_email_here>',
        toaddrs = ['$personal_email_here'],
        subject = 'Test Application Logging Email',
        credentials = ('$mailgun_email_here', '$mailgun_password_here')
    )
    handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    raise Exception('Hello, World!')  # should trigger an email

app.run()
```

Comment: You should change `app.debug = True` to `False` then it should work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was which logger the handler was added to. `Flask` uses the `werkzeug` logger to log exceptions during view functions, not the base `app.logger`.  I had to register my handler with the `werkzeug` logger:

```
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').addHandler(handler)
```

In addition, I had to include the port in `mailhost`:

```
handler = SMTPHandler(
    mailhost=('smtp.mailgun.org', 587),
    fromaddr='Application Bug Reporter <$mailgun_email_here>',
    toaddrs=['$personal_email_here'],
    subject='Test Application Logging Email',
    credentials=('$mailgun_email_here', '$mailgun_password_here')
)
```

Comment: I've tried your code but still failed to send me emails. I am using stmp.google.com and able to send messages via flask_mail extension. But still no idea how to configure it in logging..

Comment: But this doc https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/logging/#email-errors-to-admins says that you must add the handler to the app.logger. where did you read that you must use the root logger?

Comment: specifying the port did it for me (Flask 2.2.X), no need to use the `werkzeug` logger